# Trying to find the height and width of a .bmp file gets inconsistent results in processing

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, processing, bmp

I'm trying to manually draw pixels I read of a .bmp file.

This information is stored in the BMP Header. image width (4 bytes - 0x12 to 0x15), image height (4 bytes - 0x16 - 0x19) and the offset for the raw pixel data (4 bytes - 0xa to 0xd).
To find width and height, I use this:

```
byte[] bytes = loadBytes("ImageFile.bmp");
imageWidth =  ((bytes[0x12]) | (bytes[0x13])<<8 | (bytes[0x14])<<16 | (bytes[0x15])<<24) ;
imageHeight = ((bytes[0x16]) | (bytes[0x17])<<8 | (bytes[0x18])<<16 | (bytes[0x19])<<24) ;
offset = (bytes[0xa]) | (bytes[0xb])<<8 | (bytes[0xc])<<16 | (bytes[0xd])<<24;
size(imageWidth,imageHeight);
```

after that, I get accurate results: imageWidth is 600, imageHeight is 780.

but for a smaller bmp image, 250x250, after the same calculation I get the answer in 2's complement: imageWidth is -6 and imageHeight is -6.

this conversion is wierd to me,because when I view the hex data with notepad++, I get:

```
fa 00 00 00 fa 00 00 00
```

these are from bytes from 0x12 - 0x19.
they are not stored as signed values. So why do I read them as such?

And is there a single way to get the actual unsigned values regardless of the actual size?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to make them into `long`. e.g. `long imageWidth =  ((bytes[0x12]) | (bytes[0x13])<<8 | (bytes[0x14])<<16 | (bytes[0x15])<<24))  & 0xFFFFFFFFL;` It begs the question though: why are you doing this 'manually'?

Comment: You'd also need to 'unsign' each byte, but below is loads easier:

Comment: I wanted to avoid using long because the size function takes 2 ints, so I'd have to recast them. The reason I do this manually is that this is part of a compression project for a course. My goal is to compress a .bmp file, and to be able to display the compressed image without saving it to disk. So I have to draw it manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my comments above about doing it the hard way. This is tons easier:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.position(0x12);
int width = bb.getInt();
int height = bb.getInt();
```

Hard way:

```
long imageWidth = bytes[0x12] & 0xFF | (bytes[0x13] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[0x14] << 16) & 0xFF | (bytes[0x15] << 24) & 0xFF;
long imageHeight = bytes[0x16] & 0xFF | (bytes[0x17] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[0x18] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[0x19] & 0xFF) << 24;
```

Comment: This worked great :) I've used it to get all The information I needed from the file effortlessly. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I put the hard way up. I don't think it's likely that the dimension could exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so using `long` probably isn't necessary